# QComboBox Change the font color/style of selected item WITHOUT setstylesheet

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I am trying to change the font color/style of selected item of a `QComboBox`. I found answers using `setstylesheet`, but I want to use `QPalette`. But:

- I want to set the text of the selected item only, but
  using `.Text` changes all items font color. How to fix ??
- I need to also change the selected item to bold, How can
  I change it to bold ??
- Is there any better/Fast way to use than `DataFrame`, I
  feel it is a bit slow ??

The Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
        self.combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.setEditable(False)
        self.my_list = ['Item_1', 'Item_2', 'Item_3']
        self.combo.addItems(self.my_list)
        Data = {'Option Number': ['Item_1', 'Item_2', 'Item_3'],'Color': ['blue','green','red']}
        self.df = DataFrame(Data,columns= ['Option Number', 'Color'])

        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.combo_changed)

    def combo_changed(self):
        for color in ('blue', 'green', 'red'):
            if color == self.df.loc[self.df['Option Number'].str.contains(self.combo.currentText()),
                                    'Color'].iloc[0]:
                pal = self.combo.palette()
                pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, 
                            QtGui.QColor(color))
                """I want to set the text of the selected item only, 
                   but using .Text change all items font color ??"""
                pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, 
                            QtGui.QColor(color))
                """I need to also change the selected item to bold, 
                   How can I change it to bold ?? """                
                self.combo.setPalette(pal)
                """ Is there any better/Fast way to use than DataFrame, 
                    I feel it is a bit slow """
                
                del pal

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use stylesheets?

Comment: I am changing the stylesheet of the app, so I wanted to use the `Palette`

Comment: I tried `self.combo.setItemData(index, Qt.Color('red'))`, but it doesn't work, and I don't know how to add `bold` options

Comment: Sorry but your answer to my question is not very clear. Can you be more precise? Besides, have you actually tried to *properly* use stylesheets, as shown in [Customizing QComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox)?